# Is possible change operator = by a variable inside a function POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql

I don't know if this is possible, but this is the question. I try to change operator = by > if paramvalue = 0

```
AS $BODY$
declare 
operator text;
begin
operator:='=';

if (paramvalue = 0) then
    operator:='>';
end if;

select * from tablaname where id @operator 20
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think overloading an operator is more complex than what you need for this behavior. You could try using a `CASE` statement instead.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE CASE WHEN paramvalue = 0 
       THEN id > 20 
       ELSE id = paramvalue
       END
;
```

---

If you really want to overload an operator I suggest taking a look at the postgres documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/xoper.html).

Answer (score 1):

REMARK NOT TESTED !!

In your scenario solution could be...:

```
.....
if (paramvalue = 0) then
    select * from tablaname where id > 20
Else
    select * from tablaname where id = 20
end if;
```

Please read this [9.16. Conditional Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-conditional.html)

And this would be rather:

```
CASE WHEN paramvalue = 0 THEN select * from tablaname where id > 20
     ELSE select * from tablaname where id = 20
END
```